# “Access to restricted URI denied” or FileNotFound Angular Routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

**I'm trying to configure routes in Angular. Here's what I have:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="countryApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js-add routes</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', ['ngRoute']);

        countryApp.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider.
                when('/',{
                    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="country in countries">{{country.countryName}}</li></ul>',
                    controller: 'CountryListCtrl'
                    }).
                when('/:countryName',{
                    template: '<h1>TODO create country detail view</h1>',
                    controller: 'CountryDetailCtrl'
                    }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo:'/'
                    });
        });

        countryApp.controller('countryListCtrl', function($scope,$http){
            $http.get('countries.php').success(function(data){
                $scope.countries=data;
            });
        });
        countryApp.controller('countryDetailCtrl', function($scope,$routeParams){
            console.log($routeParams);
            });


    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller= "countryListCtrl"> 

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries">{{country.countryName}}</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**The code above is saved in a ng-app.html file.**

**My Question:**
ng-app.html -works
ng-app.html/ - does not work. Gives **“Access to restricted URI denied.....”** error
ng-app.html/USA - does not work. Gives **File Not Found Error Page**

When I try running the above file on a server (localhost), I get a file not found error page for both of the above "does not work" cases.

Comment: should be `ng-app.html#/USA` based on your config since you haven't set `html5Mode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @charlietfl . 
The url indeed ends up being: ng-app.html#/USA

I also wanted to point out that I a made few typos. The controllers countryListCtrl and countryDetailCtrl both start with lower case c's in the definition. But I have used uppercase C's in the routing part.